# Need help parsing this JSON

Tags: java, json, parsing, pojo, jackson-databind

I have this JSON file in following format. The first object is customer information, the second is order information, followed by n number of objects for details of each part ordered. I need to convert this to Java POJOs.

This is what JSON looks like. It's from external vendor, so I have to work with it as it is.

```
{
    "report_title": "title",
    "result_date": "08/12/2020 22:40:51",
    "company": "company name",
    "add1": "123 main st",
    "add2": null,
    "city": "some city",
    "state": "state",
    "country": "United States of America",
    "zip": "12345",
    "name": "first last",
    "username": "firstlast",
    "role": "Manager"
},
{
    "launch_date": "08/12/2020 19:05:19",
    "client": "client1",
    "order_number": "1",
    "total_orders": "1",
    "type": "type",
    "status": "Finished",
    "reference": "order reference",
    "fulfill": "some name",
    "duration": "00:07:12",
    "order title": "title",
    "order_groups": null,
    "part_nums": "1,2,3",
  },
  {
  "part_num": "1234",
  "name": "asdf",
  "other_name": "asdf",
  "manufacturer": "aasdf",
  "status": "asdfasf",
  "id": 12345,
  "title": "some title",
  "type": "Ig",
  "notes": "long winded notes",
  "impact": null,
  "solution": null,
  },
  {
  "part_num": "1235",
  "name": "asdf1",
  "other_name": "asdf1",
  "manufacturer": "aasdf1",
  "status": "asdfasf1",
  "id": 12346,
  "title": "some title",
  "type": "Ig",
  "notes": "long winded notes",
  "impact": null,
  "solution": null,
  }
...
```

I created four classes: `Customer`, `OrderInfo`, `OrderDetail` and encompassing class `Order`.

```
class Order {
    Customer customer
    OrderInfo orderInfo;
    List<OrderDetail> orderDetailList;
}
```

I am trying to use `ObjectMapper`, but I only ever get the customer object and nothing else. Any help appreciated.

EDIT:
Here is what I tried

```
public static void main (String [] args) {
      File inputFile = new File(filepath);
       String content = Files.readString(Path.of(inputFile.getPath()), StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);

       ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
      
        Customer customer = mapper.readValue(content, Customer.class);
        OrderInfo orderInfo = mapper.readValue(content, OrderInfo.class);
}


@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties( ignoreUnknown = true )
public class Customer {
    @JsonProperty("report_title") private String reportTitle;
    @JsonProperty("result_date") private String resultDate;
    @JsonProperty("company") private String company;
...
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code and your result so that we can see better what you try?

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri Added code snippet. Not sure what the downvotes are for? Care to explain?

Comment: This can be achieved with the help of the `JsonNode` of the Jackson library. You can parse the String like this `JsonNode inputNode = new ObjectMapper().readTree(inputString);` Now you can call get method on the inputNode using the index and you will get the required field.

Comment: This file is not proper JSON, in that it contains several objects. A standard JSON file should contain just one object, in which the other objects are themselves values of fields. It's not a terrible problem, but you can't just feed them into a standard JSON parser together.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I understand that. However as this json is received from external vendor, I have no control over it.

Comment: @J.J I haven't downvoted your question, but I think people were lacking information, that's why.

Comment: @AjayKrChoudhary Thanks. That was helpful.

Comment: @J.J I am glad that it helped. Happy learning man :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I posted the question little too early.

I took Ajay Kr Choudhary's suggestion and just parsed each node separately and mapped them separately. Not as efficient or automated as I wanted, but still it's better than nothing.

```
 JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(inputFile);
 Customer customer = mapper.treeToValue(rootNode.get(0), Customer.class);
 OrderInfo orderInfo = mapper.treeToValue(rootNode.get(1), OrderInfo.class);
 OrderDetail orderDetail = mapper.treeToValue(rootNode.get(2), OrderDetail.class);
```